# Rest API alternative design for use of slugs in web application

Tags: rest, api-design

I'm creating an API, but using SEO friendly slugs instead of ID's. The URL design that I've come across the most uses the plural form always like this:

```
GET /accounts -> index account
GET /accounts/:id -> show account
GET /accounts/:id/sites/:id -> nested show site
```

This is fine for a pure API with only CRUD actions, but if I do:

```
GET /accounts/new
GET /accounts/whatever
```

then that matches the account show above. A possible solution to that would be to deny accounts that generate slugs like "new" and "whatever", but it seems hackish. What I've done so far is just use singular unless it's followed by a slug or ID:

```
GET /account/new -> new account form
GET /accounts/:id -> show account
```

This may cause confusion though. It may not be optimal to mix plural and singular, but I've failed to find a good alternative for slug-friendly URLs which also support nesting of resources like the show site example above.

Are there any alternatives for designing an easy to understand URL-scheme without using any of the two schemes already mentioned?

Comment: Your REST API does not need SEO friendly slugs, your website may does.

Comment: @Ali My API returns multiple formats, including HTML.